# Can I scrape data from some site & share it on my site by giving them credits over there?

Tags: web-scraping

I want to create a site, which will represent data from some other site in a much more effective manner. For that, I am planning to **scrape** the data from them. Please let me know the answers for the below cases -

1)Is it legal to **scrape** & put that on my site? I will be giving the credits & link to the source site while sharing their data. I will be giving them profits if I will be earning from their data.

2. What if I do all the 1) things for free (e.g. - stack overflow).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming - maybe try https://law.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish :-(